ThreadPoolExecutor cant be interrupted
When i execute the following script i get outputs even after i pressed ctrl C or used interrupt in Pycharm which is the same as KeyboardInterrupt i think.
I have to press ctrl C three times to stop it. Why is shutdown(wait=False,cancel_futures=True)not working?
urls = ["facebook.com","google.com"]
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"

def build_list(directory,url):
    urllist = []
    with open(directory) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            current_url = f"{url}/{line}"
            urllist.append(current_url)
        return urllist

def process_directories(request_url):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    head = {"User-Agent": user_agent}
    try:
        response = http.request("GET", request_url, headers=head)
        print(f"Status for {request_url}: {response.status}")
        return response.status
    except (E.URLError, E.HTTPError):
        if hasattr(E.HTTPError, 'code') and E.HTTPError.code != 404:
            print("!!!!! [{}] ==> {}".format(E.HTTPError.code, request_url))
        pass
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {str(e)}")

def task(url):
    urllist = build_list("../dirlist.txt", url)
    print(f"Urllist Built For: {url}")
    for url in urllist:
        process_directories(url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as pool:
        futures = [
            pool.submit(task, url) for url in urls
        ]

        for future in futures:
            print([f._state for f in futures])
            if future.cancelled():
                continue
            try:
                n = future.result()
                print(f"{datetime.now()} - {n}")
            except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
                print(f"{datetime.now()} - EXCEPTION! {e}")
                pool.shutdown(wait=False, cancel_futures=True)
    print(f"{datetime.now()} - Run complete")

I tried incorporating shutdown and Event both didnt work.
I want the script to shutdown all threads after KeyboardInterrupt

I think you cannot cancel threads which haven't already finished before the shutdown. So some extra time may be required before interruption

@cards I dont care if the threads finish i just want to kill the entire script and all of its threads when i interrupt

if that so an idea could be to try to get the pid of the process, os.getpid(), and kill it using subproces
